# Find the constants $A$, $B$ and $C$

Tags: derivatives, constants

Our project group is stuck with this question and nobody seems to have clue so far.

> Let $f(x)=-8+2\sqrt{x}$. Then the expression $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ can be written of the form $\frac{A}{(\sqrt{Bx+Ch})+(\sqrt{x})}$, where $A, B,$ and $C$ are constants. (Note: It's possible for one or more of these constants to be $0$. Find the constants. Use your answer from above to find $lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Finally, find $f'(1), f'(2),$, and $f'(3)$.

Could somebody help out here?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math S.E.! State the question in your post with proper formatting. Then show your work/thoughts on the problem to get a favourable response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, plug the function into the definition of the derivative. You should end up with a limit which goes to $\frac{0}{0}$. Now you need to start playing around with the numbers to get it into a more useful form. An important trick for a problem like this is the following:
$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})*1= (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})*(\frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}})$$
Now, by simply multiplying out the above expression, you find that 
$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$

Try to use that type of reasoning to get a limit of the form the question asks for.

Comment: Ah that really helped me. Now I was able to get A= 2   B=1   C=1. It says I should use the asnwer from above to find the limit h->0. I don't really know where to fill the constants into or for what. Can you help?

Comment: Well, now you have a limit which is not $0/0$ so it should be fairly easy to evaluate.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm getting your hint.
I tried filling in A,B and C into A/(sqrtBx+Ch)+(sqrtx) but it doesnt give me anything meaningful. Im lost...